# Refer the same cell after applying filter in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I have the following situation:
Sheet1

[image]

and Sheet2

[image: sheet2]

In sheet 2 cell B1 is equals to Sheet1!B2 and it does not changes when I apply the filter in sheet one. Is there a way to set the filter on first sheet on the "C" and let the cell on the second sheet show 156566?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a helper column in `Sheet1`?

If so, add this a formula to `Sheet!C1`

```
=ROW()
```

and copy down for all data rows.  Hide this column if you wish

Now, Formula for `Sheet2!B1` is

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,5,Sheet1!$C:$C,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering only hides the row, so Row2 is still technically "154221".

I found this solution using formulas to return the first *visible* cell in a row:
[Find Value of First Visible Cell](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4217-excel-find-value-of-first-visible-cell.html)

Change your formula on Sheet 2 to the following and then hit *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* to apply the formula as an array:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!B2:B5,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!B2,ROW(Sheet1!B2:B5)-ROW(Sheet1!B2),0)),ROW(Sheet1!B2:B5)-ROW(Sheet1!B2)+1)))`

Note this will give the first *visible* cell on Sheet1 **within the range of B2:B5**. If you add more rows, you will need to update the range. There may be a more elegant way to handle that.